# calling -retain multiple times on the same object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

What happens when you call -retain on an object many times?  Is it OK to just release it once at when you're done using it?

Comment: What makes you ask? Do you have a situation where you think it would be helpful to call `retain` multiple times?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881880/objective-c-retain-counts-clarification/2884060#2884060) is a good way of visualizing how the retain/release model works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling -retain multiple times on the same object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170930/calling-retain-multiple-times-on-the-same-object)

Answer (score 6):

Generally you need to release the object as many times as it is retained - this is why its called reference counting.  The holders of pointers to your object call `-retain` to keep it in memory.  It will only be deallocated once its been `-release`'d the correct number of times.  Retaining it more than necessary is therefore keeping memory allocated beyond its useful life - and is called a memory leak.  The Xcode Instruments tool has a memory leak analysis tool.

Here is a good description of [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

I also agree with @Chris who comments above that [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881880/objective-c-retain-counts-clarification/2884060#2884060) describing how retain/release works is very good.